# Sonar Fail to decorate 'com.xyz.mapping.abcd' in SonarQube 4.0

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar target is failing while coming back to the parent module after analyzing the child modules. The analysis of modules da_bls, da_cdb, da_constants, da_map are successful. But sonar_project is failing

```
03:37:36  [INFO] [03:37:36.415] Execute decorators...
03:37:37  [ERROR] Fail to decorate 'com.xyz.mapping.abcd'
03:37:37  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
03:37:37  [INFO] Reactor Summary:
03:37:37  [INFO] 
03:37:37  [INFO] sonar_project ......................................... FAILURE [15:31.060s]
03:37:37  [INFO] data .............................................. SKIPPED
03:37:37  [INFO] da_bls ............................................ SUCCESS [0.013s]
03:37:37  [INFO] da_cdb ............................................ SUCCESS [0.002s]
03:37:37  [INFO] da_constants ...................................... SUCCESS [0.001s]
03:37:37  [INFO] da_map ............................................ SUCCESS [0.000s]
03:37:37  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
03:37:37  [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
03:37:37  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
03:37:37  [INFO] Total time: 15:31.714s
03:37:37  [INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 25 03:37:37 CDT 2014
03:37:37  [INFO] Final Memory: 272M/539M
03:37:37  [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
03:37:37  **[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project BBY_BBYM_BEAST_GS: Can not execute Sonar: Fail to decorate 'com.xyz.mapping.abcd': Expected single result, but got : [Snapshot[resourceId=14255,buildDate=2013-05-10 05:11:09.671,createdAt=2013-05-10 04:25:31.46,version=<null>,last=true,status=P,purgeStatus=1,scope=FIL,path=94048.94051.94055.95610.,depth=4,qualifier=CLA,rootId=94048,parentId=95610,rootProjectId=12640,period1Mode=<null>,period2Mode=<null>,period3Mode=<null>,period4Mode=<null>,period5Mode=<null>,period1Param=<null>,period2Param=<null>,period3Param=<null>,period4Param=<null>,period5Param=<null>,period1Date=<null>,period2Date=<null>,period3Date=<null>,period4Date=<null>,period5Date=<null>,id=95663], Snapshot[resourceId=14255,buildDate=2013-12-12 05:58:57.044,createdAt=2013-12-12** 04:49:46.072,version=<null>,last=true,status=P,purgeStatus=<null>,scope=FIL,path=264886.264890.264894.271231.,depth=4,qualifier=CLA,rootId=264886,parentId=271231,rootProjectId=12640,period1Mode=<null>,period2Mode=<null>,period3Mode=<null>,period4Mode=<null>,period5Mode=<null>,period1Param=<null>,period2Param=<null>,period3Param=<null>,period4Param=<null>,period5Param=<null>,period1Date=<null>,period2Date=<null>,period3Date=<null>,period4Date=<null>,period5Date=<null>,id=271276]] -> [Help 1]
03:37:37  org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on project AAX_AAXL_EAST_PS: Can not execute Sonar
```

**Google said this was bug in lower versions of SONAR (<2.8), but currently we are using SonarQube 4.0.**

Please help !!

Comment: Any answer for this one?

Comment: Nop .. had to Clear the DB and run the job again